# Сортировка строк QTableView (по verticalHeader)

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

Проблема следующая: нужно организовать возможность сортировки данных на представлении (не затрагивая модель) по строкам и столбцам. Сортировка по столбцам дело не хитрое, просто поставил прокси модель и разрешил сортировку.

```
m_pTableView->setModel(m_pController->model()); //возвращается прокси модель
m_pTableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
m_pTableView->sortByColumn(-1);
```

Но как добиться того же эффекта для строк? Метод sort у QSortFilterProxyModel принимает только номер столбца, свойств ориентации там нет.

Comment: Используя lessThan вы будете сравнивать строки чтобы установить их порядок. Переопределите этот метод и добавьте к нему ваши условия.

Comment: Daniel Protopopov, в том то и дело, мне нужно устанавливать не порядок строк. Сортируя по строке, мне нужно устанавливать порядок столбцов

Comment: в таком случае сортировку надо делать самому, ничего подходящего (кроме `headerData`) в QSortFilterProxyModel нет. Теоретически это не сложно, весь вопрос в критериях

Comment: По итогу отказался от QSortFilterProxyModel, и пришел к тому, чтобы сортировать оригинальную модель, и возвращать ее к исходному состоянию. Как оказалось, стандартная сортировка сортирует только на View (что и правильно, наверное), но из-за этого индексы прокси модели не обновляются, и новые значения по индексам после сортировки не получить (ну, или это очень не просто)